# When I introduced node-fetch in my codebase I get 'import_node_fs.promises' as it is undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vite, node-fetch

I am working on a Vite project with React and I am trying to make a request with node-fetch. I have installed the dependency as described in the docs but I am getting this logs on browser console.(Test it on chrome and edge and the give me the same error.)

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'stat' of 'import_node_fs.promises' as it is undefined.

```
VITE v4.4.9
Node.js v20.5.1
```

**package.json**

```json
"node-fetch": "^3.3.1"
```

Basically, as soon as I am introducing the fetch, my website doesn't load anymore and I get the not defined error.

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const onSubmit = async () => {
  const x = await fetch('localhost:8080');
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": [
    "vite.config.ts",
    ".eslintrc.cjs",
    ".prettierrc.cjs",
    "tailwind.config.js",
    "postcss.config.js",
    "src",
    "test"
  ],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

**vite.config.js**

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
/// <reference types="vitest" />
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    setupFiles: ['./test/setup.ts'],
  },
});
```

What am I missing here ?? Thanks guys :)

Comment: Why are you importing `node-fetch` to frontend code?

Comment: I am trying to create an SPA and I need node-fetch to make requests to the backend.

Comment: Why? Every browser has `fetch` built in. `node-fetch` is (as the name suggests) package for older versions of node js, which don't have fetch to provide a similar API as in the browser

Comment: Thats basically the answer I was looking for. I am quite new to the frontend world. Thanks getting rid of the package and the import fixed my issue.